# How to retrieve duplicate records and delete them in table A, also insert these duplicate records in another table B (in postgres)

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, records

how to retrieve duplicate records and delete them in table A, also insert these retrieved duplicate records in another table B (in postgres db)

SQL query's are required for my project.

Comment: what you have tried ?? so far?

Comment: i am new to postgres, i knew in oracle we have row id with that we can retrieve duplicate records. I am not sure how to do it in postgres

Comment: Please add the definition of the tables (ideally as `create table`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete duplicates without having a unique column you can use the `ctid` virtual column which is essentially the same thing as the `rowid` in Oracle:

```
delete from table_A t1
where ctid <> (select min(t2.ctid)
             from table_A t2
             where t1.unique_column = t2.unique_column);
```

You can use the `returning` clause to get the deleted rows and insert them into the other table:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from table_A x1
  where ctid <> (select min(t2.ctid)
                 from table_A t2
                 where t1.unique_column = t2.unique_column);

  returning * 
)
insert into table_B (col_1, col_2)
select unique_column, some_other_column
from deleted;
```

If you further want to *see* those deleted rows, you can throw in another CTE:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from table_A x1
  where ctid <> (select min(t2.ctid)
                 from table_A t2
                 where t1.unique_column = t2.unique_column);

  returning * 
), moved as (
  insert into table_B (col_1, col_2)
  select unique_column, some_other_column
  from deleted
  returning *
)
select *
from moved;
```